# Does Komodo edit have a quick format button?

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu item I'm not seeing somewhere to format my html in **Komodo Edit**?

I'm mostly worried about indentation. I have  about 1500 lines of jumbled mess from a client I need to clean up before I can start updating his page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that the paid version does have code formatters, but the free version can have them to, you just have to a: script one yourself (oooo fun!) or b: download one thats already made and ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Code formatters (including HTML) are included with the paid version of Komodo, KomodoIDE, but not in the free version, Komodo Edit.